# Angular frequency of inverted pendulum

Tags: physics, harmonic-functions

A thin vertical rod of steel is clamped at its lower end. When you push
the upper end to one side, bending the rod, the upper end moves (approximately) along an arc of a circle of radius R, and the rod opposes your push with a restoring force F = — k$\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angular displacement and K is a constant. If you attach a mass m to the upper end, what will be the frequency of
small oscillations? $\color {red} {Treat \space the\space rod\space as\space massless\space in\space your\space calculations.}$
(Hint: Think of the rod as an inverted pendulum of length R, with an extra restoring force $—k\theta$.)

let's find the angular frequency from SHO:

$$\tau = I\alpha = Rk\theta-Rmg\theta$$
$$\alpha = \frac{(Rk-Rmg)\theta}{mR^2}$$
$$\omega = \sqrt{\frac{(Rk-Rmg)}{mR^2}}$$

however, this answer is wrong the true answer is
$$\omega = \sqrt{\frac{(k-Rmg)}{mR^2}}$$

what did I get wrong?

Comment: In the differential equation I think we should use negative sign for the restoring force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the restoring action is considered as a torque, indeed the differential equation becomes

$$I\alpha = -k_{\theta}\theta+Rmg\theta \iff I \ddot\theta+(k_{\theta}-Rmg)\theta=0$$

with $$\omega = \sqrt{\frac{k_{\theta}-Rmg}{mR^2}}$$

otherwise your solution is fine.

---

As an alternative, assuming the restoring action as a horizontal force we should have $F=-kR\theta$ the differential equation becomes

$$I\alpha = -kR^2\theta+Rmg\theta \iff I \ddot\theta+(kR^2-Rmg)\theta=0$$

which leads to

$$\omega = \sqrt{\frac{kR^2-Rmg}{mR^2}}$$

Comment: Why is the restoring force considered as torque?

Comment: @SirMrpirateroberts The given solution assumes, implicitely, the restoring force as torque, and it seems a more reasonable assumption for the given problem since we are dealing with a rod of steel, at least as a first approximation. Of course it cab be also valid assum a horizontal force on the top, and in this case your solution is perfectly fine.

Comment: As noticed, you should reverse the sign in the differential equation to obtain the canonical form for the harmonic oscillator $\ddot x + \omega^2 x=0$.

Comment: I'm referring to a torsion spring model, that is $\tau = -k_{\theta}\theta$. If we assume a linear spring the force should be $F=-kR\theta$ and with this last assumption things also works fine.

Comment: Could you please show an image of the original problem statement?

Comment: @SirMrpirateroberts I've added also a solution assuming the restoring action as a horizontal force.

Comment: thank you, now I understand

Comment: You are welcome! Bye

Comment: By definition of torsional spring $\tau = -k\theta$

Comment: I have no clue in this one https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4710919/1177689