# Tension in pendulum

Tags: trigonometry, physics, harmonic-functions

The motion of a simple pendulum is given by
$\theta = A\cos\left(\sqrt{\frac g l}t\right)$
Find the tension in the string of this pendulum; assume that $\theta \ll 1$

the vertical component of the force due to gravity must be equal to the tension hence:
$$T = F\cos\theta$$
by small-angle approximation
$$\cos\theta = 1 -\frac{\theta^2}{2}$$
$$T = mg\left(1 -\frac{\theta^2}{2}\right)$$
$$T = mg\left(1-\frac{A^2\cos^2\left(\sqrt{\frac g l}t\right)}{2}\right)$$
by trigonometry:
$$T = mg\left({1-\frac{A^2}{2}+\frac{A^2}{2}\sin^2\left(\sqrt{\frac g l}t\right)}\right)$$

which is not the desired answer, what did I get wrong? true answer :
$$mg\left(1-\frac{1}{2}A^2+3\frac{A^2}{2}\sin^2\left(\sqrt{\frac g l}t\right)\right)$$

Update: I forgot to include the centripetal force in the equation hence:

$$T = Fcos\theta + F_c$$
$$F_c = \frac{mv^2} {r} = \omega^2 r$$
$$\omega^2 = (g/l)A^2\sin^2\left(\sqrt{\frac g l}t\right)$$
$$r = A$$

but this adding this to our previous answer does not reach the desired form

Comment: Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Your state 'gravity must be equal to the tension' is totally wrong, the pendulum is in a circled motion, that is, the tension not only balance the gravity, but gives the pendulum a centripetal acceleration as well.

Comment: Besides centripetal acceleration, the pendulum still have its tangential acceleration in such circle motion, yet it is not essential if you only need the force in string. A valid equation can be established along the direction of string where the tension, gravity and the centripetal acceleration be accounted into a second law equation.

Comment: @Nanayajitzuki I would like to see your answer

Comment: @Nanayajitzuki using $$T = F_c+Fcos\theta $$ is difficult to reach the desired form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your work is almost fine, note that for the centripetal part we have that $r=l$ then

$$F_c=m\omega^2l = mgA^2\sin^2\left(\sqrt{\frac g l}t\right)$$

and then

$$T = F\cos\theta + F_c=mg\left({1-\frac{A^2}{2}+\frac{A^2}{2}\sin^2\left(\sqrt{\frac g l}t\right)}\right)+mgA^2\sin^2\left(\sqrt{\frac g l}t\right)=$$

$$=mg\left(1-\frac{1}{2}A^2+3\frac{A^2}{2}\sin^2\left(\sqrt{\frac g l}t\right)\right)$$

Comment: Ahh I see I was confusion r with A when r = l

Comment: thank you @user

Comment: @SirMrpirateroberts You are welcome! Nice work. Bye

Comment: this one is significantly more difficult than the others @user https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4711622/1177689