# Quality factor of damped oscillator

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics, harmonic-functions

> If you stand on one leg and let the other dangle freely back and forth
> starting at an initial amplitude of, say, 20° or 30°, the amplitude will decay to one-half of the initial amplitude after about four swings. Regarding the dangling leg as a damped oscillator, what value of "Q" can you deduce from this?

the amplitude is no longer constant but a function where y is a constant that represents the frictional effects.
$$A(t) = A_oe^{-yt/2}$$

at a characteristic time $t^* = 2/y$ the pendulum reach equilibrium in our case taking 25 as $A_0$:
$$A(t^*) = A_0e^{-1} = 9.196 $$

The quality factor is:
$$Q = \frac{\omega}{y}$$
where Q is
$$Q = 2\pi (\frac{E}{\Delta E})$$

also:

$$\frac{t^*}{T} = \frac{Q}{\pi}$$

but $\frac{t^*}{T}$ is just the number of swings in time

now we are given the number of swings when the amplitude is half but we want the number of swings when the amplitude is at its equilibrium(9.16) let's build a function relating the amplitude after s swings

$$A(s) = 25 - \frac{12.5}{4} S$$
$$9.16 = 25 -\frac{12.5}{4}S$$
$$S = 5.06$$

now S is the number of swings such that amplitude reaches equilibrium we plug S in the formula for quality factor:

$$S = \frac{Q}{\pi}$$
$$Q = 5.06*\pi = 15.95$$

which is not the desired answer what did I get wrong?

the true answer must be around 18

Comment: We can interpret "Q" as the ringing time, or the
time it takes for the oscillations to dampen appreciably,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a [damped oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping#Damped_sine_wave) we have $A(t) = A_0 e^{-\lambda t}\cos(\omega t)$ and then

- $A(0)=A_0$
- $A(8\pi/\omega)=A_0 e^{-8\pi\frac{\lambda}{\omega}} $

with

$$A_0 e^{-8\pi\frac{\lambda}{\omega}}=\frac12 A_0 \implies e^{8\pi\frac{\lambda}{\omega}}=2\implies \zeta=\frac{\lambda}{\omega}=\frac{\log 2}{8\pi}$$

and then

$$Q=\frac1{2\zeta}=\frac{4\pi}{\log 2}\approx 18.13$$

Comment: is it valid $Q= \omega / \lambda$?

Comment: It is $Q=\frac{\omega}{2\lambda}$

Comment: the book says $Q=\omega/ \lambda$ when $Q = 2\pi\frac{E}{\Delta E}$

Comment: maybe it's because the characteristic time $t^* = 2/\lambda$

Comment: I’ve used the definition given in the wiki page. Could you show the image from the book?

Comment: [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TY6Y.png

Comment: @SirMrpirateroberts Sorry but it is very difficult to read

Comment: [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIyt3.png

Comment: @SirMrpirateroberts It depends on the definition we are referring to. If we use $A(t) = A_0 e^{-\frac \gamma 2 t}\cos(\omega t)$ then $\zeta=\frac{\gamma}{2\omega}$ and $Q=\frac1{2\zeta}=\frac{\omega}{\gamma}$.

Comment: @SirMrpirateroberts Here is a reference which use a notation similar to the one I've used.

Comment: @SirMrpirateroberts See also the related https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/148077

Comment: ok thank you...

Comment: I need your help in this one https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4750951/1177689 @user